# Call JavaScript PostBack via another Script while parsing Page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a plugin for google chrome which goes and extracts some data for a webpage and saves it to a local db. I have covered all the parsing of the pages but some info is on a different tab and for now requires me to navigate manually as it is not a basic url but a javascript. My quiestion is, is there a way to script calling a script on the page i am parsing to force the postback and if so how would i go about it. If not is there another way to solve this ?

Below are some links i would like to call from my script on the webpage

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('m_DisplayCore','DisplayInternalAction|TabSwitch|581|TAX')">Tax</a>

<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('m_DisplayCore','Redisplay|581,,0')">OC19064888</a>
```

Comment: You would need to get all the form data and post it with the right headers and cookies. I'm sure it can be done but it won't be fun.

Comment: Assuming __doPostBack is a function accessible from the global page context directly, you can call it, see [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704). Otherwise you can simply dispatch a click event e.g. element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))